# App doesn't show in launcher

Tags: android, android-studio

When I debug/ test my app from Android Studio on my phone. I don't see it in my launcher or can't even find the app by searching. It's something to do with Android Manifest right? And I don't think I made it 'launcher activity'. Would you please be able to help me? Thanks!

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gursimran.bedi.eta" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.gursimran.bedi.eta;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String TITLES[] = {"Home","Events","Mail","Shop","Travel"};
    int ICONS[] = {R.drawable.ic_alarm_add_black_48dp, R.drawable.ic_check_circle_black_48dp,
            R.drawable.ic_delete_black_48dp, R.drawable.ic_dns_black_48dp,R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_48dp};

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;                           // Declaring RecyclerView
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;                        // Declaring Adapter For Recycler View
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;            // Declaring Layout Manager as a linear layout manager
    DrawerLayout Drawer;                                  // Declaring DrawerLayout

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);

        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout), toolbar);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size
      //  mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,NAME,EMAIL,PROFILE);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
        // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
        // and header view profile picture

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager


        Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);        // Drawer object Assigned to the view
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_closed){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
                // open I am not going to put anything here)
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
            }



        }; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
        Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();               // Finally we set the drawer toggle sync State


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: show your manifest file

Comment: Add your manifest here

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Added the manifest

Comment: There is no mistake in manifest can your add your activity to

Comment: @Ammaraly Main activity?

Comment: yes of course MainActivity

Comment: start with bare bones android project in Android Studio. You must be confused about how it all works if you can't load your first project.

Comment: @inner_class7 this is actually my 3rd project. First 2 apps work flawlessly! It's just this one that is giving me some issues.

Comment: activity is also fine did you check it on another device or try to clean project rebuild it

Comment: this may happen sometimes. restart your phone and check if you have valid app icon in your project.

Answer (score 1):

@Gursimram Bedi :

For your kind information .Try this way

Clean and Rebuild your Project Then Restart your Project Too.

Actually your manifest is perfect.

Let me inform me .I hope it will helps you.

Comment: I got it fixed haha. Thanks anyway

Comment: Glad to hear .But how

Comment: @GursimranBedi can you post answer showing how you fixed it?